# Criar objetos em Runtime mais rápido

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe3, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe6

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma unit para um leitor biométrico.
Ao dar o CREATE, a unit criar vários objetos em runtime dentro de TabSheet.
Tudo está rodando perfeitamente, mas ao carregar os objetos é possível ver piscando/desenhando na tela. Alguém teve o problema semelhante? Alguma ideia de como fazer isso de forma mais elegante?

O Código:

```
constructor TFingerprint.Create (ATab : TTabSheet; AInix, AIniy : Integer);
begin
  VTab := ATab;
  // Create image
  ComImage := TImage.Create(ATab);
  Finix := AInix;
  Finiy := AIniy;
  L1 := TStringList.Create;
  L2 := TStringList.Create;
  L1.Clear;
  L2.Clear;
  FlagSync := False;
  with ComImage do
  begin
    Parent := ATab;
    Left := (VTab.ClientWidth-128*4-24-217) div 2;
    Top := 8;
    Height := 128;
    Width := 128;
    Picture.LoadFromFile('conn_off.png');
  end;
  FP_IDS := TStringList.Create;
  // ComPort
  ComPortA := TComPort.Create(ATab);
  with ComPortA do
  begin
    BaudRate := br115200;
    Port := 'COM5';
    Buffer.InputSize := 2048;
    Buffer.OutputSize := 2048;
    OnAfterOpen := ComPortAAfterOpen;
    OnBeforeOpen := ComPortABeforeClose;
    OnError := ComPortAError;
    //OnRxChar := ComPortARxChar;
  end;
  // ComDataPacket
  ComDataPacketA := TComDataPacket.Create(ATab);
  with ComDataPacketA do
  begin
    ComPort := ComPortA;
    StartString := MD_STX;
    StopString := MD_ETX;
    OnPacket := COmDataPacket1Packet;
  end;

  // Buttons
  btnCaptureFP := TBitBtn.Create(ATab);
  with btnCaptureFP do
  begin
    Parent := ATab;
    Caption := '   Capturar   '#13#10'Digital';
    Width := 217;
    Height := 97;
    Left := VTab.ClientWidth-Width-8;
    Top := 16;
    Font.Height := -23;
    Font.Name := 'Tahoma';
    NumGlyphs := 2;
    Glyph.LoadFromFile('glyph-fingerprint.bmp');
    OnClick := OnClickCaptureFP;
    Enabled := False;
  end;
  btnDeleteFP := TBitBtn.Create(ATab);
  with btnDeleteFP do
  begin
    Parent := ATab;
    Caption := '    Apagar    '#13#10'Digital';
    Width := 217;
    Height := 97;
    Left := VTab.ClientWidth-Width-8;
    Top := 129;
    Font.Height := -23;
    Font.Name := 'Tahoma';
    NumGlyphs := 2;
    Glyph.LoadFromFile('glyph-fingerprint-delete.bmp');
    OnClick := OnClickDeleteFP;
  end;
  btnSyncFP := TBitBtn.Create(ATab);
  with btnSyncFP do
  begin
    Parent := ATab;
    Caption := ' Sincronizar '#13#10'Digital';
    Width := 217;
    Height := 97;
    Left := VTab.ClientWidth-Width-8;
    Top := 242;
    Font.Height := -23;
    Font.Name := 'Tahoma';
    NumGlyphs := 2;
    Glyph.LoadFromFile('glyph-sync.bmp');
    OnClick := OnClickSyncFP;
    Enabled := False;
  end;
  btnExitFP := TBitBtn.Create(ATab);
  with btnExitFP do
  begin
    Parent := ATab;
    Caption := '      Sair      ';
    Width := 217;
    Height := 97;
    Left := VTab.ClientWidth-Width-8;
    Top := 355;
    Font.Height := -23;
    Font.Name := 'Tahoma';
    NumGlyphs := 2;
    Glyph.LoadFromFile('exit.bmp');
  end;


 // StringGrid
  FPGrid := TStringGrid.Create(ATab);
  with FPGrid do
  begin
    Parent := ATab;
    FixedCols := 0;
    Font.Name := 'Tahoma';
    Font.Size := 12;
    ColCount := 4;
    Left := 8;
    Top := 144;
    Width := ATab.ClientWidth-24-217;
    Height := (VTab.ClientHeight-ComImage.Top-ComImage.Height-16);
    Cells[0,0] := 'Nome';
    Cells[1,0] := 'ID';
    Cells[2,0] := 'Grupo';
    Cells[3,0] := 'Leitor ID';
    Cells[4,0] := 'Level';
    Cells[5,0] := 'Status';
    ColWidths[0] := 210;
    ColWidths[1] := 100;
    ColWidths[2] := 190;
    ColWidths[3] := 90;
    ScrollBars := ssVertical;
    Options := Options + [goRowSelect];
    OnClick := OnClickFPGrid;
  end;
  // ProgressBar
  prgBar := TProgressBar.Create(ATab);
  with prgBar do
  begin
    Parent := ATab;
    Width := 217;
    Height := 16;
    Left := VTab.ClientWidth-Width-8;
    Top := 468;
    Position := 0;
  end;
  SendMessage(prgBar.Handle, PBM_SETBARCOLOR,0,clLime);
  // Label
  lblBar := TLabel.Create(ATab);
  with lblBar do
  begin
    Parent := ATab;
    Left := prgBar.Left;
    Top := prgBar.Top + prgBar.Height + 8;
    Font.Name := 'Tahoma';
    Font.Color := clWhite;
  end;

  // Load Users
  LoadUsers2;

  // Check first empty FP
  FPGrid.Row := 1;
  while not(FPGrid.Cells[3,FPGrid.Row] = '') and (FPGrid.Row < FPGrid.RowCount-1) do
    FPGrid.Row := FPGrid.Row + 1;

  ComPortA.Open;
  // GetUsers
  SendTelegram(GET_USERS);
  ComImage.Visible := True;
end;
```

No meio tem o carregamento do Glyphs que tem entre 17K a 20K.

Comment: Você poderia ocultar a Tabsheet, ou iniciar com ela oculta e torna-la visivel apenas quando todos os componentes tiverem sido criados. Além de esconder os efeitos indesejados, torna a criação mais rápida porque alguns eventos não serão chamados.

Comment: Sua dica foi muito boa, fiz isso e na hora que vira visível cria um delay e ai começa a piscar tudo para aparecer.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode setar a property DoubleBuffered do form para True e, ainda, travar o canvas:

`Canvas.Lock;
try
  ...
  criação dos componentes
  ...
finnaly
  Canvas.Unlock;
end;`

Comment: Muito obrigado.... melhorou... estou quase lá....ainda falta algo.

Answer (score 1):

É como o Ricardo Alves falo, questão de buffer.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoubleBuffered := true;
end;
```

Isso resolve. Usava para fazer pequenos jogos em Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o "[Application.ProcessMessages](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_ProcessMessages.html)" em alguns pontos do seu código.

Mais informações:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181713/i-do-not-understand-what-application-processmessages-in-delphi-is-doing

Comment: O pior que continua uma piscadeira....o   código acima está em uma unit e os objetos estão sendo criados dentro de uma TabSheet